# Clicking to add new row in table removing entered data

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have written code that adds a new row in the table when the button is clicked. If I enter values and then click the button, the data is deleted. Why?

```js
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function(){
document.querySelector('table tbody').innerHTML += document.querySelector('table tbody tr').innerHTML;
});
```

```html
<button id="add">Add</button>

<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="number" placeholder="test" min="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" placeholder="test" min="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" placeholder="test" min="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" placeholder="test" min="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" checked></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider using the append() method.

```html
<body>
    <button id="add">Add</button>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tableBody">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="number" placeholder="test" min="1"></td>
            <td><input type="number" placeholder="test" min="1"></td>
            <td><input type="number" placeholder="test" min="1"></td>
            <td><input type="number" placeholder="test" min="1"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" checked></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        let count = 0;

        function newInputElement(type, placeholder="", min=1) {
            let input = document.createElement('input');
            input.type = type;
            input.id = type + count;

            if(type == 'number') {
                input.placeholder = placeholder;
                input.min = min;
            } else {
                console.log("add another type for support");
            }

            count++;
            return input.outerHTML;
        }

        function addNewRowOfInputs(target, destination, triggerEvent) {
            document.getElementById(target).addEventListener(triggerEvent, function() {
                let row = document.createElement('tr');
                
                row.innerHTML =
                '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + newInputElement('number', 'test') + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + newInputElement('number', 'test') + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + newInputElement('number', 'test') + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + newInputElement('number', 'test') + '</td>' +
                '<td><input type="checkbox" checked></td>' +
                '<tr>';

                document.getElementById(destination).append(row);
            });
        }

        addNewRowOfInputs('add', 'tableBody', 'click');
    </script>
</body>
```

By doing this, you can add on to the existing content without overwriting it's content.

Comment: It works. Thank you! Do you know why my method didn't work properly?

Comment: I changed your code a bit to make it more usable and redable.
`row.innerHTML = document.querySelector('table tbody tr').innerHTML;`

Comment: @test, as far as I can see,  you did nothing wrong. Logically, I'd have done the same. The most I can come up with is that you overwritten your code each time the button is pressed. (Taking the default html structure and copy/pasting it) on top of the already written code/input.

Comment: Don't expose variables globally!